# Is there an easier way to make these axios post reqest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, mailgun

I'm trying to upload multiple images to cloudinary via api in my react app using axios.
I'm new to promises, so I'm not sure if I'm using the right approach here.

I am able to upload all the images to cloudinary; however, the response I get is the confusing part, as with the response I need to pass the images' urls to an object, so I can send them to an email using mailgun.

Here is my code to upload the images:

```
if(payment === "success") {
axios
    .all([
        props.imgForProduct.map((img) => {
            const fd = new FormData();
            fd.append("file", img);
            fd.append("upload_preset", "sublimation");
            return axios
                .post(
                    "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/ahkji7ation/image/upload",
                    fd
                )
                .then(async (res) => {
                    return (imgUrl = res.data.secure_url);
                })
                .catch((err) => console.log(err));
        }),

        props.screenshot.map((img) => {
            const fd = new FormData();
            fd.append("file", img);
            fd.append("upload_preset", "sublimation");
            return axios
                .post(
                    "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/ahkji7ation/image/upload",
                    fd
                )
                .then(async (res) => {
                    return (imgScrSht = res.data.secure_url);
                })
                .catch((err) => console.log(err));
        }),
    ])
    .then(
        axios.spread(async (...res) => {
            imgUrl.push(res[0][0]);
            imgScrSht.push(res[1][0]);

            let dataObj = {
                email: props.email,
                img: imgUrl,
                screenshot: imgScrSht,
            };
            console.log(dataObj);

            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                axios.post("/email_to_ayp_sublimation", dataObj);
                resolve((res) => {
                    console.log(res);
                });
                reject((err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                });
            });
        })
    )
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));    
}
```

When I console log the dataObj this is what I'm sending in the last call (the new Promise):

```
screenshot: Array(1)
0: Promise {<resolved>: "https://res.cloudinary.com/ahkji7ation/image/u… 
590871936/ahkji7ation/kqebmkjfj0prmyygls2y.jpg"}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I'm receiving [object Object] in the backend, instead of the url I need. Can anybody help me sort this out? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is with your axios.all(...) code. You are passing in two values but the values have .map inside them which are returning urls. Because of this, axios.post() on both indexes will upload the images but axios.all() will have the return values from the .map() function which is an array of promises. You can try something like this.

```
async function uploadImages(imgForProduct, screenshots) {
  const URL = "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/ahkji7ation/image/upload";

  //Collect all the form datas for img and screenshots
  const imgForProductFormData = imgForProduct.map((img) => {
    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("file", img);
    fd.append("upload_preset", "sublimation");
    return fd;
  });
  const screenShotsFormData = screenshots.map((img) => {
    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("file", img);
    fd.append("upload_preset", "sublimation");
    return fd;
  });

  const imgForProductRequests = imgForProductFormData.map(
    async (fd) => await axios.post(URL, fd).catch((err) => null)
  );
  const screenshotsRequests = screenShotsFormData.map(
    async (fd) => await axios.post(URL, fd).catch((err) => null)
  );

  try {
    const imgForProductResponses = await axios.all(imgForProductRequests);
    imgForProductResponses.map((res) => (res[0] ? imgUrl.push(res.data.secure_url) : null));

    const screenshotsResponses = await axios.all(screenshotsRequests);
    screenshotsResponses.map((res) => (res[0] ?imgScrSht.push(res.data.secure_url) : null));

    let dataObj = {
      email: props.email,
      img: imgUrl,
      screenshot: imgScrSht,
    };
    console.log(dataObj);

    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      axios.post("/email_to_ayp_sublimation", dataObj);
      resolve((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      });
      reject((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    });
  } catch(err) {console.log(err)}
}
```

Hope this works!

Comment: Yeah, that made the trick, a lot cleaner this way, I can now see the proper responses. Thanks so much